# Flipper cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, react-native, flipper

`Flipper` is a platform for debugging iOS, Android and React Native apps.
I have downloaded the `Flipper` app from https://fbflipper.com/, but I can't run it.

[image: Error image]

macOS version: `Catalina 10.15.3`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Just **Right Click > Open**. Or alternatively, open System Preferences, Security & Privacy, General tab, and Click 'Open Anyway'. [Guide on support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40616/mac)

- *Still not working?:* **Right Click > Open**, again. If you don't have certain **permissions** on your mac (for example on your work laptop), you'd need to run `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Flipper.app` instead.

---

### Problem

- This is a general problem (security feature called [Gatekeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatekeeper_(macOS))) with apps on macOS where the developer is not registered with Apple (Paying $99/year) and so has not notarized their application. Specifically, Gatekeeper saves a quarantine flag on a downloaded file. So alternatively, you can remove this flag for your specific file, or disable Gatekeeper entirely so you never have this issue again.
- A nice explanation by the Terraform team who faced the same issue:

  > Indeed the new version of MacOS is stricter about running software you've downloaded that isn't signed with an Apple developer key. Terraform distributions are signed with a HashiCorp key with signatures distributed out of band on releases.hashicorp.com, but MacOS Catalina is requiring participation in Apple's developer program specifically, and Terraform is currently not built to support that. [source](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23033)
- **From an app developer stand point:** Applications on macOS need a `Developer ID` [certificate](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/) to verify that we are trusted developers. This also provides access to macOS capabilities: e.g. CloudKit, Apple Push Notifications. If you're making an app, you can need to go into developer.apple.com to create an Apple Developer ID certificate, or create on in XCode (in some cases).

Comment: That's just so strange that the company backed by Facebook can't afford to spend $100/year to keep their users calm.

Comment: @dstdnk hahaha nice point.

Comment: It's not just the cost ($100/year), but the company process and tooling/automation that would need to be created for the notarization process - which I wrote a guide for CLI apps https://orth.uk/macos-clis. Xcode configuration and `Xcodebuild` commands can be very tiring to get correct.

Answer (score 56):

You can run following command to remove the warning and allow un-authorized app to run on macOS Catalina:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Flipper.app
```

Comment: i love the internet

Comment: So strange that you can run this command, without elevation, and Flipper will now open.

Answer (score 17):

Go to System preference, Security and Privacy and choose Opneanyway:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to either [run or build from source](https://github.com/facebook/flipper#building-from-source).
Helpful if you're on a work computer with tighter application security settings.

Prerequisites:

- NodeJS (https://nodejs.org/en/)
- Yarn (https://yarnpkg.com)

**Running from source**

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/flipper.git
cd flipper/desktop
yarn
yarn start
```

**Building from source**

```
yarn build --mac --version $buildNumber
```

For Building from source, you should do it in the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/flipper.git
cd flipper/desktop
yarn
yarn build --mac --version $buildNumber
```

Note: I've noticed building from source as of Aug 2020 `0.53.0` has some issues for me, so would recommend running from source if you need to use this.

Answer (score 1):

***brew install --cask flipper***

and after that you'll see message 'flipper was blocked from ... '
press **Open Anyway**

Comment: You have to go to settings-> Privacy & Security-> Open Anyway